# Laravel scout indexing problem with ElasticSearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I'm trying to index the information from the Laravel Models to Elasticsearch, so i've implemented

```
"babenkoivan/elastic-migrations": "^1.6",
"babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver": "^1.4",
"babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver-plus": "^2.3",
```

But when i try to index the information to ES, using jobs table, the payload says something like:

{"uuid":"48b608d1-d429-4060-8f4c-0595a338db86","displayName":"Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable","job":"Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"maxExceptions":null,"failOnTimeout":false,"backoff":null,"timeout":null,"retryUntil":null,"data":{"commandName":"Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable","command":"O:33:"Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable":10:{s:6:"models";O:45:"Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier":4:{s:5:"class";s:19:"App\Models\Products";s:2:"id";a:500:{i:0;i:3;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:5;i:3;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:5;i:8;i:6;i:9;i:7;i:10;i:8;i:11;i:9;i:12;i:10;i:13;i:11;i:15;i:12;i:16;i:13;i:17;i:14;i:18;i:15;i:19;i:16;i:20;i:17;i:21;i:18;i:22;i:19;i:23;i:20;i:24;i:21;i:25;i:22;i:26;i:23;i:27;i:24;i:28;i:25;i:29;i:26;i:30;i:27;i:31;i:28;i:32;i:29;i:33;i:30;i:34;i:31;i:35;i:32;i:36;i:33;i:37;i:34;i:38;i:35;i:39;i:36;i:40;i:37;i:41;i:38;i:42;i:39;i:43;i:40;i:44;i:41;i:45;i:42;i:46;i:43;i:47;i:44;i:48;i:45;i:49;i:46;i:51;i:47;i:52;i:48;i:53;i:49;i:54;i:50;i:55;i:51;i:56;i:52;i:57;i:53;i:58;i:54;i:59;i:55;i:60;i:56;i:61;i:57;i:62;i:58;i:63;i:59;i:64;i:60;i:65;i:61;i:66;i:62;i:67;i:63;i:68;i:64;i:69;i:65;i:70;i:66;i:71;i:67;i:72;i:68;i:73;i:69;i:74;i:70;i:75;i:71;i:76;i:72;i:77;i:73;i:78;i:74;i:79;i:75;i:80;i:76;i:81;i:77;i:82;i:78;i:83;i:79;i:84;i:80;i:85;i:81;i:86;i:82;i:87;i:83;i:88;i:84;i:89;i:85;i:90;i:86;i:91;i:87;i:92;i:88;i:93;i:89;i:94;i:90;i:95;i:91;i:96;i:92;i:97;i:93;i:98;i:94;i:99;i:95;i:100;i:96;i:101;i:97;i:102;i:98;i:103;i:99;i:104;i:100;i:105;i:101;i:106;i:102;i:107;i:103;i:108;i:104;i:109;i:105;i:110;i:106;i:111;i:107;i:112;i:108;i:113;i:109;i:114;i:110;i:115;i:111;i:116;i:112;i:117;i:113;i:118;i:114;i:119;i:115;i:120;i:116;i:121;i:117;i:122;i:118;i:123;i:119;i:124;i:120;i:125;i:121;i:126;i:122;i:127;i:123;i:128;i:124;i:129;i:125;i:130;i:126;i:131;i:127;i:132;i:128;i:133;i:129;i:134;i:130;i:135;i:131;i:136;i:132;i:137;i:133;i:138;i:134;i:139;i:135;i:140;i:136;i:141;i:137;i:142;i:138;i:143;i:139;i:144;i:140;i:145;i:141;i:146;i:142;i:147;i:143;i:148;i:144;i:149;i:145;i:150;i:146;i:151;i:147;i:152;i:148;i:153;i:149;i:154;i:150;i:155;i:151;i:156;i:152;i:157;i:153;i:158;i:154;i:159;i:155;i:160;i:156;i:161;i:157;i:162;i:158;i:163;i:159;i:164;i:160;i:165;i:161;i:166;i:162;i:167;i:163;i:168;i:164;i:169;i:165;i:170;i:166;i:171;i:167;i:172;i:168;i:173;i:169;i:174;i:170;i:175;i:171;i:176;i:172;i:177;i:173;i:178;i:174;i:179;i:175;i:180;i:176;i:181;i:177;i:182;i:178;i:183;i:179;i:185;i:180;i:186;i:181;i:187;i:182;i:188;i:183;i:189;i:184;i:204;i:185;i:205;i:186;i:206;i:187;i:207;i:188;i:208;i:189;i:209;i:190;i:210;i:191;i:211;i:192;i:212;i:193;i:213;i:194;i:214;i:195;i:216;i:196;i:217;i:197;i:218;i:198;i:219;i:199;i:220;i:200;i:223;i:201;i:224;i:202;i:225;i:203;i:226;i:204;i:227;i:205;i:228;i:206;i:229;i:207;i:230;i:208;i:231;i:209;i:232;i:210;i:233;i:211;i:234;i:212;i:235;i:213;i:236;i:214;i:237;i:215;i:238;i:216;i:239;i:217;i:240;i:218;i:241;i:219;i:242;i:220;i:243;i:221;i:244;i:222;i:245;i:223;i:246;i:224;i:247;i:225;i:248;i:226;i:249;i:227;i:250;i:228;i:251;i:229;i:252;i:230;i:253;i:231;i:254;i:232;i:256;i:233;i:262;i:234;i:263;i:235;i:264;i:236;i:266;i:237;i:268;i:238;i:269;i:239;i:270;i:240;i:271;i:241;i:272;i:242;i:273;i:243;i:274;i:244;i:275;i:245;i:276;i:246;i:277;i:247;i:278;i:248;i:279;i:249;i:280;i:250;i:281;i:251;i:282;i:252;i:285;i:253;i:286;i:254;i:287;i:255;i:288;i:256;i:289;i:257;i:290;i:258;i:291;i:259;i:292;i:260;i:293;i:261;i:294;i:262;i:295;i:263;i:296;i:264;i:297;i:265;i:298;i:266;i:299;i:267;i:300;i:268;i:301;i:269;i:302;i:270;i:303;i:271;i:304;i:272;i:305;i:273;i:306;i:274;i:307;i:275;i:308;i:276;i:309;i:277;i:310;i:278;i:311;i:279;i:312;i:280;i:313;i:281;i:314;i:282;i:315;i:283;i:316;i:284;i:317;i:285;i:318;i:286;i:319;i:287;i:320;i:288;i:321;i:289;i:322;i:290;i:323;i:291;i:324;i:292;i:325;i:293;i:326;i:294;i:327;i:295;i:328;i:296;i:329;i:297;i:330;i:298;i:331;i:299;i:332;i:300;i:333;i:301;i:334;i:302;i:335;i:303;i:336;i:304;i:337;i:305;i:338;i:306;i:339;i:307;i:340;i:308;i:341;i:309;i:342;i:310;i:343;i:311;i:344;i:312;i:345;i:313;i:346;i:314;i:347;i:315;i:348;i:316;i:349;i:317;i:350;i:318;i:351;i:319;i:352;i:320;i:353;i:321;i:354;i:322;i:355;i:323;i:356;i:324;i:357;i:325;i:358;i:326;i:359;i:327;i:360;i:328;i:361;i:329;i:362;i:330;i:364;i:331;i:365;i:332;i:366;i:333;i:367;i:334;i:368;i:335;i:369;i:336;i:370;i:337;i:371;i:338;i:372;i:339;i:373;i:340;i:374;i:341;i:375;i:342;i:376;i:343;i:377;i:344;i:378;i:345;i:379;i:346;i:380;i:347;i:381;i:348;i:382;i:349;i:383;i:350;i:384;i:351;i:385;i:352;i:386;i:353;i:387;i:354;i:388;i:355;i:389;i:356;i:390;i:357;i:391;i:358;i:392;i:359;i:393;i:360;i:394;i:361;i:395;i:362;i:396;i:363;i:397;i:364;i:398;i:365;i:399;i:366;i:400;i:367;i:401;i:368;i:402;i:369;i:403;i:370;i:404;i:371;i:405;i:372;i:406;i:373;i:407;i:374;i:408;i:375;i:409;i:376;i:411;i:377;i:412;i:378;i:413;i:379;i:414;i:380;i:415;i:381;i:416;i:382;i:417;i:383;i:418;i:384;i:419;i:385;i:420;i:386;i:421;i:387;i:422;i:388;i:423;i:389;i:424;i:390;i:425;i:391;i:426;i:392;i:427;i:393;i:428;i:394;i:429;i:395;i:430;i:396;i:431;i:397;i:432;i:398;i:433;i:399;i:434;i:400;i:435;i:401;i:436;i:402;i:437;i:403;i:438;i:404;i:439;i:405;i:440;i:406;i:441;i:407;i:442;i:408;i:443;i:409;i:444;i:410;i:445;i:411;i:446;i:412;i:447;i:413;i:448;i:414;i:449;i:415;i:450;i:416;i:451;i:417;i:452;i:418;i:453;i:419;i:454;i:420;i:455;i:421;i:456;i:422;i:457;i:423;i:458;i:424;i:459;i:425;i:460;i:426;i:461;i:427;i:462;i:428;i:463;i:429;i:464;i:430;i:465;i:431;i:466;i:432;i:467;i:433;i:468;i:434;i:469;i:435;i:470;i:436;i:471;i:437;i:472;i:438;i:473;i:439;i:474;i:440;i:475;i:441;i:476;i:442;i:477;i:443;i:478;i:444;i:479;i:445;i:480;i:446;i:481;i:447;i:482;i:448;i:483;i:449;i:484;i:450;i:485;i:451;i:486;i:452;i:487;i:453;i:488;i:454;i:489;i:455;i:490;i:456;i:491;i:457;i:492;i:458;i:493;i:459;i:494;i:460;i:495;i:461;i:496;i:462;i:497;i:463;i:498;i:464;i:499;i:465;i:500;i:466;i:501;i:467;i:502;i:468;i:503;i:469;i:504;i:470;i:505;i:471;i:506;i:472;i:507;i:473;i:508;i:474;i:509;i:475;i:510;i:476;i:511;i:477;i:512;i:478;i:513;i:479;i:514;i:480;i:515;i:481;i:516;i:482;i:517;i:483;i:518;i:484;i:519;i:485;i:520;i:486;i:521;i:487;i:522;i:488;i:523;i:489;i:524;i:490;i:525;i:491;i:526;i:492;i:527;i:493;i:528;i:494;i:529;i:495;i:530;i:496;i:531;i:497;i:532;i:498;i:533;i:499;i:534;}s:9:"relations";a:0:{}s:10:"connection";s:5:"mysql";}s:10:"connection";s:8:"database";s:5:"queue";N;s:15:"chainConnection";N;s:10:"chainQueue";N;s:19:"chainCatchCallbacks";N;s:5:"delay";N;s:11:"afterCommit";N;s:10:"middleware";a:0:{}s:7:"chained";a:0:{}}"}}

So now i dont know if there is a problem with ES or with my Laravel app?

I'm using Laravel 8 BTW

Thanks

Comment: That blob is your job payload, not the error exception. What's the actual issue?